# How can I make bold only page numbers in List of Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, bold

Dear All How can I make bold only page numbers and "Table 1.2 :" in List of Table? You can reach the package from below link under this title Lateks Tez Şablon/Latex Thesis Template  (Yeni) :
 **http://www.fbe.itu.edu.tr/Pages.aspx?app=1&pID=174**

Thanks in advance.

The partial code for LoT is given below:

```
`\renewcommand\listoftables{
    \vspace*{\ChapterUstenBosluk}
    {\chapter*{\listtablename}
    \vspace*{-20pt}
    \hfill\vspace*{0.5truecm}{\bf\underline{\if@Ingilizce Page\else Sayfa\fi}}}

    \let\orig@numberline\numberline

    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}
    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{%
     \orig@numberline{\bf\tablename\ ##1}\hspace{-12pt}{\bf:}\hspace{7pt}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{{\protect\listtablenameToC}}
    \setlength{\th@oldparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\LoTparskip}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\th@oldparskip}
    \let\numberline\orig@numberline
    }`
```

Comment: Actually, the formatting is at a much lower level.  \@dottedtocline currently specifies \normalfont\normalcolor for page numbers.

Comment: How can I change \normalfont with \bfseries for onlypage numbers? If I try to transform page numbers to bold, caption explanations become bold also. I want to avoid from this issue because of formatting restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You can find `\@dottedtcoline` in `source2e` from CTAN.  The macro `\patchcmd` is a convenient way to make small changes in big macros, provided the text to be replaced occurs only once.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for \patchcmd
\usepackage{caption}% for captionof

\begin{document}
\bgroup% local change
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{\normalfont}{\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother
\listoftables
\egroup

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\captionof{table}{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, your suggestion does not work in my  case. Partial given code is part of a class file.

Comment: Your \documentclass file uses \bf?   My condolences.  In any case, \@starttoc does most of the work.  What you need to check is \l@table.

Comment: There is not \l@table in the code. Is there an equivalent expression for this one?

Comment: In the lot file for my answer you will find `\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces test\relax }}{1}` which in turn calls the macro `\l@table{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces test\relax }}{1}` (in fact, that is ALL it does).  Try `\makeatletter \meaning\l@table \makeatother`

Comment: I tried this one also. However output doesn't change. I guess I did something wrong. If you have time, Please look at the package and help me. I am grateful for your help.

Comment: \meaning prints the contents of the macro (more or less).  Just because you can't find the code doesn't mean it wasn't read off another file.